# how to specify OneToOne relationship in spring boot project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwdWn.png)

I need one to one relationship where the **publications** depends on the **teacher_profile_post** so it will have foreign key relationship, I have tired but some how it doesnt work for me.

Can somebody help me where I am missing or doing mistake.

teacher_profile_post entity

```
public class TeacherProfilePost {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;//tipo objetuales no primitivos

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "teacherProfilePost", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Publication publication;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "student_id")
private Student student;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "teacher_id")
private Teacher teacher;}
```

publications entity

```
public class Publication {


@OneToOne(mappedBy = "publication", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private CommentReport commentReport;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
private Publication parent;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String comment;

@Column(nullable = false)
private int like;

@Column(nullable = false)
private int dislike;}
```

I need to know how to make this relationship because I have tried different ways and it does not give me results.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by making below changes in your entity

you need to add Id column in publication entity and mapped the same id into other entity like below

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "teacherProfilePost", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "publication", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Publication publication
```

if you want to it Vice versa then you need to add below code in your **Publication** entity

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "teacher_profile_post ")
private TeacherProfilePost teacherProfilePost ;
```

That's because this is a bidirectional relationship. The Publication side of the relationship is called the non-owning side.

Comment: So what I want to do is to use the main key of teacherprofilepost in publications so that there is a dependency like this in the image.

Comment: I have updated my answer. hope it will helps you